# Check browser load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a method to check whether a browser's TAB page has been reloaded or not in C#?

Comment: -1 No details (How can we know so it is about firefox?)

Answer (score 0):

If webBrowser load is compleeted, **DocumentCompleted** event have been fired.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to know about the firefox I'm using, not the embeded browser in my winform.